# Observable request inside Angular pipe for HTML filtering

Tags: javascript, angular, asynchronous, angular-observable

I know there are async pipes, which using using observables you can subscribe to and get values as they update.

I am trying to create a simple pipe, which would get a translation of a classificator using its code, but it does so using an observable, so it is async. Could I somehow wait for the aync action to complete and then return the result? What would be the optimal way?
I don't think async Pipe is what I am looking for, because would basically  be a component with it's own HTML.

Code

```
@Pipe({
    name: 'translate'
})
export class Translate implements PipeTransform {

    constructor(public translateContext: TranslateContext) {
    }

    transform(value: any, classification: string): any {
     this.translateContext.getTranslation(classification).subscribe(res => {
            return res.get(value.toString());
        });
    }
}
```

I would like to use the following pipe in HTML as follows

```
{{code | translate: classificator }}
```

How could I resolve this that from the pipe it would get this value.

```
return res.get(value.toString());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change to:

```
transform(value: any, classification: string): any {
 return this.translateContext.getTranslation(classification).map(res => {
        return res.get(value.toString());
    });
}
```

And use it like:

```
{{code | translate:classificator | async }}
```

The idea here is to return an observable containing your value and then subscribe to the observable using `async`. This will display the mapped value in your template.

Comment: yeah, I am a rookie Angular dev, I thought about this solution in my head , but thought it would not work. Thanks for the solution, it was to easy :)

Comment: Glad it helped :)

Comment: @DarkFeud Don't forget to accept the answer if you find it to be the correct solution.